# In which books where I can find this formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, soft-question

Given a matrix $A\in M_n(K)$ such that
\begin{align*}
P_A(\lambda)\,&=\,(-1)^n\big(\lambda -\lambda_1\big)^{m_1}\cdots\big(\lambda -\lambda_p\big)^{m_p},
\newline m_A(\lambda)\,&=\,\big(\lambda -\lambda_1\big)^{k_1}\cdots\big(\lambda -\lambda_p\big)^{k_p}.
\end{align*}
I know there is a formula for counting number of the Jordan blocks of size $d$. Specifically, for each $1\leq d\leq k_i$, the number of Jordan blocks of size $d$ is given by
\begin{align*}
2\dim E^d(\lambda_i)-\dim E^{d+1}(\lambda_i)-\dim E^{d-1}(\lambda_i)
\end{align*}
where $E^d(\lambda_i) = \ker(A-\lambda_i)^d$.

Could anyone tell me in which book I can find this formula and its proof ? Thanks

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3675160/305862) is a proof.

Comment: Yeah, but do you know is there any book that has this formula and its proof ? since I need to cite a reference book in my article

Comment: No, I haven't such a book in reference.